# How to gain access to pricing in tiers of a subscription with a single expanded request on a customer id

Tags: stripe-payments

Previously in 2018-02-28 version of the stripe api, in request for subscriptions from a customer:

```
var customer = await stripe.customers.retrieve(
   stripe_customer_id_used,
   {
     expand: ['subscriptions'],
   }
);
```

the plan tier data list would be included in the response...in the latest 2020-08-27 version of the stripe api its missing the tier plan data list that is includes the pricing.

If attempting to expand the list this way:

```
var customer = await stripe.customers.retrieve(
   stripe_customer_id_used,
   {
     expand: ['subscriptions.data.items.data.plan.data.tiers'],
   }
);
```

I go beyond the "4 levels" rule.

Is there another to grab the plan tier data in a single request...or am i going to now have to loop through this response, and re-request this data from stripe adding many requests to stripe...which i want to avoid.

What am I missing? Any guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior changed in [version 2020-08-27](https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades#2020-08-27):

> - The `subscriptions` property on Customers is no longer included by default. You can [expand the list](https://stripe.com/docs/api#expanding_objects) but for performance reasons we recommended against doing so unless needed.
> - The `tiers` property on Plan is no longer included by default. You can [expand the list](https://stripe.com/docs/api#expanding_objects) but for performance reasons we recommended against doing so unless needed.

To work around this you can [make this specific API request with the API version prior to the changes mentioned above](https://stripe.com/docs/api/versioning), which is [version 2020-03-02](https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades#2020-03-02).  Doing so would look something like this:

```js
var customer = await stripe.customers.retrieve(
   stripe_customer_id_used,
   {
     expand: ['subscriptions'],
   },
   {
     apiVersion: '2020-03-02',
   }
);
```

Comment: I think the change they made for removing the tiers data was a mistake, and I made that feature suggestion. They should run a study on how many people change api version before running this query or are running extra queries to gain access to the tiers data directly after retrieving expanded subscription data to validate weather or not removing the tiers data is truly saving overhead and was a good choice in this scenario. But as it stands now, I agree, your response is the best method. Thank you Justin for your response.

Comment: Where can I find a list of which strings to use when expanding? I'm trying to expand the tiers, but "tiers" and "data.tiers" don't work.

Comment: If you're trying to expand `tiers` on a Plan it would be `tiers`.  Can you post a separate question with your code and further details?